# How to insert Text into a HTML file in body tag in Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I am new to PowerShell and I have a file.html which I need to insert into Email-message. I am able to insert the html file into email body. But I want to insert some content in the beginning of the email regarding the context.
I can get the html content into a parameter with below command, but I need to insert some text in the body, before sending the Email message. Note that the parameter already has all tags with data.
$body = Get-Content -Path C:\file.html -Raw

Comment: HTML is plain text, so you're looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875617/insert-content-into-text-file-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

The `Send-MailMessage` has an `-attachments` parameter, and also an -body parameter, which you can use. If you want to have additional text you can add your text

```
send-MailMessage -body "(Your text here) $($body)" (Your remaining parameters)
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the simplest option of all.

Answer (score 0):

If as you say the HTML body *has all tags*, this could be as simple as:

```
$textToInsert = 'This describes the body below'
$body = Get-Content -Path C:\file.html -Raw
$parts = $body -split '<body>', 2
$body = '{0}<body><p>{1}</p>{2}' -f $parts[0], $textToInsert, $parts[1]
```